# Why is the main page showing only the user login form?

Tags: 8

I just installed the Paragraphs module along with all of the other accompanying modules including the demo module. The demo module created the demo page successfully but it also decided to change my site's default front page to the demo page.

When I changed the front page field back to the default null text, anonymous users now see nothing but this login form instead of my former front page. Registered users are sent to their user page, e.g. http://example.com/user/1.

Before installing the demo, my front page showed any articles that were promoted to the front page and had no login screen. Could this be a permissions issue? What might have happened and how can I restore the main page?

[image: Front page with long only]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default front page at /admin/config/system/site-information for a standard installation isn't an empty string, it's `/node`, despite the text underneath the field that reads:

> Optionally, specify a relative URL to display as the front page. Leave blank to display the default front page.

Comment: The default is `/user/login` which when you are logged in redirects to your user page. See https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/8.8.6/core/modules/system/src/Form/SiteInformationForm.php#L132. I guess that the standard profile then sets it to `/node`.

Comment: That line of code you found is interesting Leymannx - I'm guessing it's legacy code since `/node` has been the default since at least Drupal 5. You are correct that the standard profile sets the front page to `/node`: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/8.8.6/core/profiles/standard/config/install/system.site.yml#L8